# Compare String function in mysql by words

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to create a search function in mysql. In order to make the search result more reliability i need to compare two string by words. Inputs are 2 strings and output is number word two strings match. In MySql i did as below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CompareStrings`(str1 VARCHAR(255),str2 VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS double
BEGIN
DECLARE cur_position INT DEFAULT 1 ; 
DECLARE remainder TEXT;
DECLARE cur_string VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE delimiter_length TINYINT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE numberMatch INT;
DECLARE total INT;
DECLARE result DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE delim VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE string2 VARCHAR(255);
SET delim = ' ';

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS SplitString1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SplitString1 (
    SplitString1ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    val VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS SplitString2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SplitString2 (
    SplitString1ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    val VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

SET remainder = str1;
SET delimiter_length = CHAR_LENGTH(delim);

WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(remainder) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 DO
    SET cur_position = INSTR(remainder, delim);
    IF cur_position = 0 THEN
        SET cur_string = remainder;

    ELSE
        SET cur_string = LEFT(remainder, cur_position - 1);
    END IF;
    IF TRIM(cur_string) != '' THEN
        INSERT INTO SplitString1(val) VALUES (cur_string);
    END IF;
    SET remainder = SUBSTRING(remainder, cur_position + delimiter_length);
END WHILE;
SET remainder = str2;
SET cur_position = 1;
WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(remainder) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 DO
    SET cur_position = INSTR(remainder, delim);
    IF cur_position = 0 THEN
        SET cur_string = remainder;

    ELSE
        SET cur_string = LEFT(remainder, cur_position - 1);
    END IF;
    IF TRIM(cur_string) != '' THEN
        INSERT INTO SplitString2(val) VALUES (cur_string);
    END IF;
    SET remainder = SUBSTRING(remainder, cur_position + delimiter_length);
END WHILE;
SELECT count(*) INTO numberMatch 
FROM SplitString1 s1 JOIN SplitString2 s2 ON s1.val = s2.val;
RETURN result;
END
```

The idea is create two temporary table store each word and then compare these 2 tables. The result is good but the performace is awful. Anybody has better idea, please give me an advice. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work as stated.

The logic is sound but you have not assigned any value to your `result` variable. Hence this function will always return 0. Replace:

```
RETURN result;
```

with

```
RETURN numberMatch;
```

Also replace:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CompareStrings`(str1 VARCHAR(255),str2 VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS double
```

with

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CompareStrings`(str1 VARCHAR(255),str2 VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS double READS SQL DATA
```

As far as efficiency goes it looks pretty efficient. When you say 'performance is awful' - what constitutes 'awful'? Have you got any benchmark figures e.g. x calls took y millis?

Comment: sorry for mistake in my post, but infact, as you mentioned i returned numbermatch, and i sured that this function worked well. The problem was it took me approximately 0.015s in comparing two strings in benchmark and combination with search function it took me about 5-6s with just 5k records in database. Anyway, thank you for your comment.